# Кириллица в Intellij IDEA

Tags: кодировка, intellij-idea, кириллица

Русские символы(кириллица) выводится на экран в виде иероглифов(Р‘Р°Р±РєР° Р·Р° Р’РЅСѓС‡РєСѓ) подскажите пожалуйста как разобраться с кодировкой?

Comment: Думаю, это дубликат. Ответы на выбор https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[intellij-idea]+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Открыть файл в кодировке Windows-1251, если конечно вы ещё не успели сохранить.